# Counter On Navbar Product Angular

Tags: angular, e-commerce, counter, product, cart

I have a problem,

I'm creating a simple ecommerce where I have the product component and the Cart component.

In the navbar i put a counter with routerLink to the cart page.

I would like to implement the logic that the count is updated when the product is purchased.
I use a service.

What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @Giuseppe Zaccaria. Its always a good practice to add a code snippet of whatever you have tried so far. That helps other to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't provided any code, it's not possible to give you an exact answer. However, you can try this solution:

Use an input in your navbar component to track the count of purchased items. Use Angular's text interpolation `{{ }}` in the navbar html template to display the value of the input.

**navbar.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'nav-bar',
    template: `
      <div class="navbar">
        <span id="purchaseCounter"> Items Purchased: {{ purchasedCount }}</span>
      </div>
    `
})
export class NavBarComponent {
    @Input() purchasedCount: number;

    constructor() { }
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```html
<nav-bar [purchasedCount]="numPurchased"></nav-bar>
```

numPurchased is a variable in the parent component which is passed as an input to the nav-bar component

**parent.component.ts**

```js
numPurchased: number = 0; // on component init, 0 items purchased

// function that is called when purchase occurs
doPurchase() {
    /* whatever code to process a purchase */
    
    // if purchase is successful, increment the count 
    this.numPurchased++;
}
```

Any changes to numPurchased in the parent component will be passed to the (child) nav-bar component